# Why is emacsclient not reusing the existing frame?

Tags: frames, emacsclient

I have emacs running as a daemon (using `launchctl`), and I can use `emacsclient --socket-name=socket -n -r -a ''` and open a frame just fine.  But if I run it again (say, to open some file), it opens another frame.  Am I wrong in assuming that `-r` should make it open the buffer for that file in the already existing frame?

This is using emacs 29.1 on an M2 mac, if that's useful context.

EDIT:  I've tried using builds from https://emacsformacos.com, Homebrew, and building directly from source, and I get the same result from all three.  The `-r` option to `emacsclient` doesn't reuse frames. What the eff?

Comment: It should work the way you expected.  It's not starting a new server each time, is it?  Each new frame is part of the same single Emacs instance?

Comment: I mean, I don't THINK it's starting a new server.  I don't see a second instance of Emacs in the process list, and I don't start the server from my init.el.

Comment: Yeah, I can see common buffers in both, and typing in one frame shows the text in the other frame, so I'm confident that another instance of Emacs isn't starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this works, but removing the `-r` option makes `emacsclient` reuse the frame as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the switches by typing

```
emacsclient --help
```

in a terminal. Doing this, you'll see the following, along with several other helpful options:

```
-r, --reuse-frame       Create a new frame if none exists, otherwise
                        use the current Emacs frame
```